# Should I ask new Question or modify my old post?

Tags: support, questions

I some time ago asked [This Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96366/why-does-a-fluorescent-tube-lamp-flicker-before-lighting-up) but i also want to ask "Why it makes sound like 'ting', 'ting' before lighting up ?"

should I modify the post or post a new question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a separate issue from what you were asking about in the earlier question, so you should post it separately.